# Duplicate results in NetSuite Contact search

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

Can someone help me understand why I get duplicate results on a Contact search in NetSuite *only* when I include a **Customer** field as a result column? Below are steps for how I am reproducing this problem.

1. Create a new Contact search
2. Add a single criterion: **Internal ID** is any of 230, 597, 1808
3. For results, return just a single column, **Internal ID**
4. Submit the search. 3 results are returned as expected (screenshot below).

[image: Contact Search: 3 results]

5. Return to the criteria for the search
6. For results, add a second column, **Customer : Internal ID**
7. Submit the search again. This time *six* (6) results are returned (screenshot below).

[image: Contact Search: 6 results]

What is incredible to me is not only are there double the number of results, but the results actually appear to be *unique* based on the fact that the **Customer : Internal ID** values are different. What causes this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the field you give as result. If you many number of field in the result section, each result field that match your search criteria or filter will be shown irrespective of what is already displayed(ie,duplicates will be shown).
Use criteria to filter it out  or reduce the result field

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar interaction to the "main line" criteria on a transaction search.  a contact is a record in itself.  When searching for a contact it returns a singular one.  As soon as you tell it to return an internal ID of a related document or customer you will find that sometimes a contact can exist in two places at once.  So your second set of results basically says that (for example) Contact 597 is connected to customer 168 and customer 167.  Contact records are not the same as a customer record.

Answer (score 0):

Each contact has its own internal id, however, the same contact might show up to different records because NetSuite allows you to attach a contact to more than one customers/sub-customers. Therefore when you add customer: internal id it's pulling out all the customers that have the same contact on their records. You can add another column that shows the customer name/id under results and see if this is what happened.